# "His TVs are broken" is a routine action in a passive voice form or a state of the verb "to be"?

Tags: word-usage, passive-voice, past-participles

We all know that simple present tense shows Repeated Actions such as a habit, a hobby, a daily event, a scheduled event or something that often happens ([Source](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/simplepresent.html))

Eg: *I play tennis.*

We also know that Non-Continuous Verbs or Stative verbs used in Simple Present to express an action is happening or is not happening now ([Source](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/simplepresent.html))

Ex: *I am here now* = *I am staying here now*.

It is wrong to say "*I am being here now*".

To be  is also use to show a state. Eg: *She is fat.*

Now, let see this sentence:

*He breaks His TVs* (a regular event)

And its passive voice: *His TVs are broken (by him)* (a regular event in passive form)

But we also have "**broken** as an adjective ([Source](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/broken?q=broken))" Eg: *a broke leg*

So, *His TVs are broken* is **a regular event in a passive form or a thing that is happening or a state**?

**How do we know it is a regular event in a passive form or a state?**

Comment: Could you check the links please? They aren't working at the moment. Thanks.

Comment: I'm unsure if "a broke leg" is grammatically correct as I think the adjective form of broke refers to someone who has exhausted their supply of money. "a broken leg" could be the appropriate usage.